# Python 3 In Memory Zipfile Error. string argument expected, got 'bytes'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code to create an in memory zip file that throws an error running in Python 3.

```
from io import StringIO
from pprint import pprint
import zipfile


in_memory_data = StringIO()
in_memory_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(
    in_memory_data, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False)
in_memory_zip.debug = 3

filename_in_zip = 'test_filename.txt'
file_contents = 'asdf'

in_memory_zip.writestr(filename_in_zip, file_contents)
```

To be clear this is only a Python 3 problem. I can run the code fine on Python 2. To be exact I'm using Python 3.4.3. The stack trace is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "in_memory_zip_debug.py", line 14, in <module>
    in_memory_zip.writestr(filename_in_zip, file_contents)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1453, in writestr
    self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader(zip64))
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
Exception ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x1006e1ef0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1466, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1573, in close
    self.fp.write(endrec)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Answer (score 78):

`ZipFile` writes its data as bytes, not strings. This means you'll have to use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO` on Python 3.

The distinction between bytes and strings is new in Python 3. The [six](https://six.readthedocs.io/) compatibility library has a `BytesIO` class for Python 2 if you want your program to be compatible with both.

Comment: This is confusing because the error message from the OP implies the exact opposite problem. He's providing a string value since that's what the error message states is the expected argument type.

Comment: except OP is using writestr method and not write, so it should indeed be a string and not bytes, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 27):

The problem is that `io.StringIO()` is being used as the memory buffer, when it needs to be `io.BytesIO`. The error is occurring because the zipfile code is eventually calling the StringIO().Write() with bytes when StringIO expects a string.

Once it's changed to `BytesIO()`, it works:

```
from io import BytesIO
from pprint import pprint
import zipfile


in_memory_data = BytesIO()
in_memory_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(
    in_memory_data, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False)
in_memory_zip.debug = 3

filename_in_zip = 'test_filename.txt'
file_contents = 'asdf'

in_memory_zip.writestr(filename_in_zip, file_contents)
```