# GZip and output file

Tags: python, json, gzip

I'm having difficulty with the following code (which is simplified from a larger application I'm working on in Python).

```
from io import StringIO
import gzip

jsonString = 'JSON encoded string here created by a previous process in the application'

out = StringIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
    f.write(str.encode(jsonString))

# Write the file once finished rather than streaming it - uncomment the next line to see file locally.
with open("out_" + currenttimestamp + ".json.gz", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(out.getvalue())
```

When this runs I get the following error:

```
File "d:\Development\AWS\TwitterCompetitionsStreaming.py", line 61, in on_status
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\gzip.py", line 204, in __init__
    self._write_gzip_header(compresslevel)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\gzip.py", line 232, in _write_gzip_header
    self.fileobj.write(b'\037\213')             # magic header
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

PS ignore the rubbish indenting here...I know it doesn't look right.

What I'm wanting to do is to create a json file and gzip it in place in memory before saving the gzipped file to the filesystem (windows).  I know I've gone about this the wrong way and could do with a pointer.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost duplicate of [Python 3 In Memory Zipfile Error. string argument expected, got 'bytes' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075135/python-3-in-memory-zipfile-error-string-argument-expected-got-bytes) (`ZipFile` versus `GzipFile`) -- but the answer is the same. Understand the distinction between str and bytes in Python 3 clearly, then use the correct one.

Comment: There are also [python 3.x - TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903409/typeerror-string-argument-expected-got-bytes)  and [python - string argument expected, got 'bytes' in buffer.write - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797043/string-argument-expected-got-bytes-in-buffer-write)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use bytes everywhere when working with gzip instead of strings and text. First, use BytesIO instead of StringIO. Second, mode should be `'wb'` for bytes instead of `'w'` (last is for text) (samely `'ab'` instead of `'a'` when appending), here `'b'` character means "bytes". Full corrected code below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY8/T8MwEMV3f4pTGJqobdSWCSQWBhAMdOjAiJz0krjyP9mXhvTLh3NaiQE8WGff3Xvv50fqnL2fpiY4A8qBMt4FgueRML7txe3ZXpQX4hSdPVBQtoUnWLwf9h@AtnZHPEK8fncYEOqAkvivGkGCD3hWro9cuBpjBGWBOgTpvVa1JOXsQgjXE0veTPNCDIq62bR85etFacwbvlx14jEeXoFh25RiqBYFyAjNowA@TTkERZhznvKaLf9NXRTzjKj7ENASKYORpPFJZ7fZbdeb7Xr3wHHu4DOpzEGTLzhbp8qq2DFYkNwI3JU2gaM0iV0RrKFnT2NYfN61@E2glWUlBxFvYtrVUuuxvFI6jzbPmOkrgyX8ibaErEwEZXvJVpANVfYfLq@XLdJZ6h5zxpymHw)

```
from io import BytesIO
import gzip

jsonString = 'JSON encoded string here created by a previous process in the application'

out = BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj = out, mode = 'wb') as f:
    f.write(str.encode(jsonString))
    
currenttimestamp = '2021-01-29'

# Write the file once finished rather than streaming it - uncomment the next line to see file locally.
with open("out_" + currenttimestamp + ".json.gz", "wb") as f:
    f.write(out.getvalue())
```